# Convert XML tags to attributes in arbitrary locations with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

We have an XML format that is actually just HTML with some extra gubbins. It defines which HTML elements are editable, and which attributes are editable thereof.

Here's an example

```
<img src="images/placeholder.jpg" 
     alt="Placeholder" 
     width="600" 
     height="250" 
     border="0">
  <var attr="src" />
  <var attr="height" ok="150-300" />
</img>
```

The XML is so the templates are easier to write but I need to convert it to valid(ish) HTML. To do this I want to collapse it into:

```
<img src="images/placeholder.jpg" 
     alt="Placeholder" 
     width="600" 
     height="250" 
     border="0"
     editable="src height" 
     constraints="height:150-300">
```

I can do this for `<img>`, but the problem is that the `<var>` tags can actually appear as a child of any element in the page. In all cases the algorithm for converting it to attributes is the same but what I can't work out how to do is specify an XSLT template that can match the parent element of a `<var>` tag. I tried `match="var/.."` but this turned out to be invalid.

The alternative would be to match the `<var>`s and add them as attributes to their parents, but I believe that at this point in the processing that particular ship would already have sailed.

Is this doable?

Thankies

**Answer!**

I combined the more complete answer with Dimitre's usefully accurate answer to form the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="*[var]">
        <xsl:copy >
            <xsl:attribute name="editable">
                <xsl:for-each select="var[@attr]">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat(@attr,
                            substring(' ',
                                1 div (position()!=last())))"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="constraints">
                <xsl:for-each select="var[@ok]">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat(@attr,':',@ok,
                            substring(';',
                                1 div (position()!=last())))"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="var">
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately the exact answer Alejandro gave didn't work straight away (still not sure why),but this combination of his answer and Dmitri's answer seems to have done the job nicely :)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the most natural XSLT solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides Dimitre's exact answer to your question, other approach would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|var"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::var)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="var"/>
    <xsl:template match="var[1]">
        <xsl:attribute name="editable">
            <xsl:for-each select="../var/@attr">
                <xsl:value-of
                     select="concat(.,
                                    substring(' ',
                                              1 div (position()!=last())))"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="constraints">
            <xsl:for-each select="../var/@ok">
                <xsl:value-of
                     select="concat(../@attr,':',.,
                                    substring(';',
                                              1 div (position()!=last())))"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<img src="images/placeholder.jpg" 
     alt="Placeholder" 
     width="600" 
     height="250" 
     border="0" 
     editable="src height" 
     constraints="height:150-300"></img>
```

Comment: Kudos for the epic foresight to exemplify all the other things I was going to have had to spend a lot of time researching, like the concat stuff :) I accepted this answer for its completeness

Comment: hmm I'm going to have to hack at this since my simple example isn't working. But I think I'm on the right lines :)

Comment: @Altreus: The problem could be because `var` elements aren't the first child, including white space only text nodes that they are meaninful in (X)HTML. Easy solution involves a minor modification of the identity rule. Check my edit.

Answer (score 4):

> what I can't work out how to do is
>   specify an XSLT template that can
>   match the parent element of a `<var>`
>   tag

**Use**:

```
<xsl:template match="*[var]">
```

Comment: +1, yep. @Altreus, this means "match any element that has a child element named 'var'".

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could mark two as the accepted answer. While this answer is exactly what I was asking and shows me something I didn't know, I accepted the more complete answer for having the immense foresight to answer all the other questions about this example that I was inevitably going to end up with :D

Answer (score 1):

I would consider building a local variable (`<xsl:variable>`) as the parser gets to the `<img>` tag and construct a NEW `<img ...>` explicitly within that variable, walking through any `<var>` children it finds (`<xsl:foreach ...>` anyone?) close the variable when they are exhausted ... then just write the variable out?